# How to set minimum row-height of a cell in combination with setting Rows.AutoFit() in Excel using vsto?

Tags: vsto, excel-2013

I would like to know is it possible to set the minimum row height of all cells in a row and if the value overflows that row-height then use autofit(). So, i wanted to use both both options in combination using vsto, Excel-2013.

Please let me know your suggestions.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to resolve the above problem:

```
ExcelRange.Rows.AutoFit();
if (ExcelRange.Rows.Height < some_number1)
{
    workingRange.Rows.RowHeight = some_number2;
}
```